# FullCalender - How to automatically fetch and display previous events?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to display previous events in fullCalendar. But there's a problem: after you define an event and then refresh the page the events disappear.

Is there any way that I can fetch all the details from all the previous events and display them on the calendar?

This is my code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        selectable: true,
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventClick: function(info) {
            info.jsEvent.preventDefault(); // don't let the browser navigate

            if (info.event.url) {
                window.open(info.event.url);
            }
        },
        dateClick: function(info) {
            endDate = info.dateStr;
            localStorage.enddate = info.dateStr;
            setTimeout(cal, 1000);

            function cal() {
                if (imgUrl !== ' ' && today <= endDate) {
                    calendar.addEvent({
                        title : `Post ${l++}`,
                        url   : `${imgUrl}`,
                        start : `${today}`,
                        end   : `${endDate}`
                    });

                    imgUrl = ' ';
                } else if (today > endDate) {
                    alert('Please select a date that is in the future!');
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }

            var today = new Date();
            var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
            var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
            today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

            const date1 = new Date(`${today}`);
            const date2 = new Date(`${endDate}`);
            seconds = date2 - date1;
            console.log(seconds);
        }
    });

    calendar.render();
});
```

Comment: Where do you keep events data? Local Storage? Database?

Comment: @AhmetFiratKeler I didn't store it. I mean I don't know how to store it.

Comment: You need to save the event data somewhere, and then reload it via an event feed. You could store in the browser as JSON in localstorage, if you just want it available to the same user. Or you could send the data via AJAX and store it in a central server if you need the calendar data available to many people. Fullcalendar is just a user interface component - it doesn't store or track any data, except while it's currently loaded. When you refresh the page, just like all Javascript code, it resets. But it's up to you where/how you want to store the data...we can't tell you what to do.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source tells you all about fetching event data from places where it's stored back into fullcalendar.

Comment: I have a working example but a bit different version of it. In this one, I'm getting events from database using Ajax. I show less options for mobile devices checking screen sizes. I also show some kind of modal for editing when you click on calendar event. This should be your road map.